# How do I access request headers in a rails API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm struggling to access headers sent to my API in Grape.  In my test specs I am sending a GET request with an email in a  header. I want to extract the email sent in the header as it hits the API and record it in an instance of my Audit model.  However I can't access the header here through request.headers, any idea what I can do?

Comment: With grape just use `headers` instead of `request.headers`.

Comment: Yes, this is it, I needed to put it in a before block too.  Thanks!